# Can electrons be ionised with a wave below threshold frequency but infinite amplitude?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, electrons, atomic-physics, frequency

Electrons of a certain atom can only be ionised with a wave with frequency above a threshold.

What if a wave's frequency was below the threshold but it had infinite amplitude? Because even though not enough energy is provided by the frequency, the amount of energy delivered because of the amplitude is infinite, so wouldn't the atom be ionised?

Comment: Google non--lineat optical milti-photon phenomena.

Answer (score 1):

[Schottky effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schottky_effect) lets one use *static* electric field to eject electrons from a material. So you don't even need an infinite amplitude: finite amplitude and zero frequency is enough, provided the amplitude is sufficient.

Similarly, applying high enough static electric field to a single atom will rip it apart.

Comment: What if we have non-zero frequency that is below the ionisation frequency?

Comment: @FellowTraveller large enough field will accelerate atomic electrons, so that they'll leave the nuclear potential barrier. Since initially they were highly confined by the Coulomb force, after leaving the wave packets will rapidly spread. Thus, on the opposite phase of the EM wave these electrons will not return to the initial confined state (because the field is polarized along one direction), and will instead be scattered by the nuclear field. So you have high probability of detection of an electron far from the nucleus.

Comment: I got curious and did some reading and found out that we can also in fact recombine the electron provided we have the right frequency (phase matching) and this is how they generate high harmonics!